# Implementing a dead man's switch for running code

Tags: python, linux, bash

I have some Python code that's a bit buggy. It runs in an infinite loop and I expect it to print something about once every 50 milliseconds, but sometimes it hangs and stops printing or even outright segfaults. Unfortunately, the problem seems to be fairly rare, so I've had trouble nailing down the exact cause of the issue. I want to have the code up and running while I debug the problem, so while I try to figure it out, I'd like to create a dead man's switch that runs my code, but stops if the code doesn't print anything in a certain time frame (say, 5 seconds) or exits and finally executes a command to notify me that something went wrong (e.g. 'spd-say terminated').

I put this into the terminal for my first attempt at this:

```
python alert.py; spd-say terminated;
```

Unfortunately, it didn't seem to work - at this point I realized that the code was not only crashing but also hanging (and I'm also not sure whether this would even work if the code crashes). Unfortunately, I'm not very familiar with bash yet (I assume that's what I'm using when I run stuff in the terminal), and I'm not sure how I could set up something like what I want. I'm also open to using other things besides bash to do this if it would be particularly difficult to do for some reason.

What would be the best way to implement what I want to do?

Comment: Maybe add another loop independent of the first one that prints something with the same interval. If both loops stop producing output then there's some error in the code that trips it. If new loop is printing, but old one doesn't then maybe you original loop simply doesn't have any output to print.

Comment: I believe many folks use a watchdog thread. I'm not sure how popular they are with Python, though. See, for example, [watchdog.py](https://gist.github.com/wolever/e894d3a956c15044b2e4708f5e9d204d).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could run two python programs with a pipeline between them. On one side you have you buggy script writing something on the pipeline every less than 5 seconds. On the receiving end of the pipeline you have a very simple script that checks how long it has been since it last received anything. If this time is more than 5 seconds.

This way you decouple your watchdog from your buggy script.